# Text is hiding while I spam the keyboard

Tags: html, css

I was doing this  inside the div but when I spam the keyboard the text suddenly is hiding on the second line I know the `overflow:hidden` is not the one causing it.

Why is it causing to hide is there any alternative solution for it?

BTW the text is `contenteditable`

[image]

HERE is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xR9Xx/

Comment: Is the `top:20px;` a requirement? Without it the problem seems to go away.

Comment: yea i need it so I can center the text inside the div

Answer (score 0):

## Option: #1

Set the `overflow` from `hidden` to `auto`, for the following style. If you are looking for a scrollbar to appear.

```
.profilestatus .statusTextBox {
    height: 100px;
    left: 60px;
    outline: medium none;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 400px;
}
```

## Option: #2

Add the `word-wrap` and `width` properties to the following style.

```
.profilestatus .statusTextBox .statusText {
    position:relative;
    font-family:Calibri, Arial;
    font-size:95%;
    top:20px;
    font-weight:400;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width:400px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/maheshsapkal/xR9Xx/1/)**

Comment: Sorry but I dont want any scrollbars on it.

Answer (score 0):

if ok instead of `position:relative;` make it `float:left;`

```
 .profilestatus .statusTextBox .statusText {
          float:left;
          text-align:center;
            font-family:Calibri,Arial;
            font-size:95%;
            font-weight:400;
        }
```

working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/xR9Xx/8/)

Comment: then top: 20px is not needed anymore